# Fastest way to generate a change set between 2 sql tables or CSV files

Tags: sqlite, csv, diff

I am looking for a fast way to get the "deltas" between the 2 csv files (2 GB each).

(The CSV files are loaded to SQLite table where the CSV file first line are the column names, the 0th column is a unique key)

The output is supposed to be something along the lines of:

"Inserts" =... , "deletes" , "Updates" from new.csv to old.csv

The 0th column of the CSV can be considered unique

So something along the lines of:

```
File1:

id | c1 | c2 | c3 | ....
1  | v1 | v2 | v3 |

File2:

id | c1  | c2  | c3  | ....
1  | v1' | v2' | v3' |
```

Comment: What distinguishes an updated row from a row that was deleted and then inserted with different values? Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: meaning that the key from the second csv existed in the first csv but the column values had changed

Comment: You did not mention any key.

Comment: ok - the keys are from the 0th column

Comment: SQL does not have column numbers.

Comment: The CSV has column names which are the sql table column names

Answer (score 0):

When you have text files, the easiest way would be to sort them by their ID values (`sort -n`) and then use `diff`.

In SQL, you can get inserted and deleted rows by checking which IDs do not occur in the other table:

```
SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM Table1);

SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM Table2);
```

To get changed rows (here, with the new values), remove all identical rows with [EXCEPT](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound):

```
SELECT * FROM Table2
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM Table1;
```

Comment: That depends. The first two SQL queries can be sped up with an index on `id` (which is created automatically for a primary key).